# Groovy script to replace \r\n, \n and \t with " "

Tags: regex, groovy, apache-nifi

I am using Apache NiFi to build my dataflow and the actual data I am dealing with at the moment is made of delimited values. I would like to use ExecuteScript and in order to do so I have put together a simple Groovy script that should do the following:

1) replace the current delimiter with a pipe (|)

2) replace \r\n and \tab with " "

The reason for this script is to do some data cleaning and wrangling on a dataset that shows the following issues:

a) text (often long) cuts across lines via `\tab` or `\r\n`. This can happen before a full stop, but it is not consistent.

b) blank lines (currently the script does not touch on this yet)

1) was easily done, but the code for 2) does not seem to remove tabulations and carriage returns and I am not sure why. Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
    inputStream.eachLine { line ->
        def a = line.replaceAll('\t', ' ').replaceAll('\r\n', ' ').replaceAll('¦', '|')
        outputStream.write("${a}\n".toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    }
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you certain the tabs are actually ASCII code 9h, and the "carriage returns" are a combination of carriage return and line feed/newline (ASCII Dh and Ah)? See http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: If you are iterating through the input stream line-by-line, I don't think you can replace the newlines separating the lines, or join the two resulting lines.  Maybe you could do a regex replace separately?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, thanks for this. I am not very familiar with all the differences in character encodings, however I have brought up all the characters in Notepad++ via the option "Show all characters" and LF is at the end of each line. In some cases is OK, in other it arbitrarily breaks long text and goes to a new line. I have also compared the current output with the original one and I managed to get rid of \tab and CR LF.

Answer (score 2):

As you traverse the lines with `eachLine` you already removed all `\r` and `\n` as the `eachLine` splits on them and then gives you the result in turn. If you want to remove linebreak characters, you cannot use `eachLine` or rather you can simply leave out the `\n` from the `write()` call.

As for the '\t' are you sure those are really actually '\t' characters?

Besides that you shouldn't use `replaceAll()` of you don't use regular expressions. Use `replace()` instead.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Have a look at my comment above where I say that the characters I see now are simply the LF at the end of each line. The \t characters were already removed by the code, the issue I believe I am left with is the following: 
- each line containing delimited values ends with LF, however I should really have LF if and only if the last two values are numerical|numerical.

Comment: The cases in which the LF should be removed are those in which long text is somehow broken and moved one line forward (LF, in fact). This is the only thing I can think of in order to distinguish between the LF I still would like to preserve and those I would like to remove. I am not sure how to go about it, though.

Comment: One more thing, If I leave out the \n at the end of the write() call, I am returned with a single long String including all headers and all values per line. I was trying to avoid that. I am doing some further manipulations later for which I need to have all expected delimited values line by line. Thank you!

Comment: Well then make the `\n` conditional. Check whether your last two values are `numerical|numerical` and only emit the `\n` if they are. What's the problem?

Comment: Yep, that is what I thought too, I actually came to realise it would be easy when I said it!

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with this script, however it seems to remove all `LF` at the end of all lines and output the content to one single line. I wonder whether you can spot anything obviously wrong in the code. I am expecting to have a `\n` only at the end of the lines holding the format: `|digit`

```
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

def flowFile = session.get()
if (!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, { inputStream, outputStream ->
    inputStream.eachLine { line ->
        def a = line.replace('\t', ' ').replace('¦', '|')
        if (${a}.endWith('\\d$'))
            outputStream.write("${a}\n".toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        else {
            outputStream.write("${a}".toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        }
    }

} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```